# Fast way to search/view within a 1MB text file with ".xml" extension in Android

Tags: android, plain-text, reading

I have a 1 megabyte text file on my Android SD card.
It has a `.xml` filename extension that I can't change, but the content is actually human-readable.

I often need to search into the file and read a paragraph or two around the hit line(s).

I tried [Jota](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.sblo.pandora.jota) but:

- Takes 15 seconds to load
- Does unnecessary syntax highlighting
- Search UI is not intuitive: no special indication when no hit
- Unnecessary edition feature

Actually I don't need the file to be loaded totally. Just let me first enter the search string, and then show me 10 lines above/below, if that can speed up things.

Requirements:

- Remembers last open file
- Search feature accessible within a second of launching the app (opens very fast, possibly by not loading the whole file, or not loading before search is performed)
- Command-line style is OK, but I would like to avoid the overhead of typing a command. If tapping an app launcher can open a terminal, prompt me for a search string, and display 10 lines above/below, that would be OK.
- Free
- Bonus for indexing the file at first open and when modified

Comment: My opinion is to try the recommended alternatives until you find one that fits your requirements.

Comment: I'm tempted to recommend a terminal emulator and suggest using `grep` :) Could you please [edit] your question and list your requirements? Must it be graphical (or would my terminal/grep thingy do)? Any must/must-not/nice-to-haves?

Comment: Thanks! But oh what a pity, your first requirement renders my suggestion "not an answer" :) Is that mandatory? If not, some "Tasker-Fu" might jump in: query search text from user, show a file picker, run grep (with the corresponding parameters to include X lines "around the finding"), show results. Not that I know exactly *how* to implement this, but it would certainly be possible. Hm, maybe one could even make it remember the last opened file. Well, but Tasker's not "free" …